# Linking Twilio with the Lync SIP Endpoint

Tags: twilio, lync

I'm looking to forward my Twilio to my Microsoft Lync SIP Endpoint.

Firstly, getting a Dial->Sip: SIP URI DNS does not resolve or resolves to an non-public IP address when it is set up correctly (or as per the MS docs).

_sip._tls.mydomain.co.uk SRV 1 443 sipdir.online.lync.com Priority: 100
_sipfederationtls._tcp.mydomain.co.uk SRV 1 5061 sipfed.online.lync.com Priority: 100

Has anyone done this or know where I might be going wrong?

Comment: Twilio evangelist here.

Would you mind sending me an email?  I'd love to work direct with you to get this working.  devin [at] twilio [dot] com.

Comment: Did you ever get this working?